# How to include files with die(); function?

Tags: php, file, function, include, die

file1.php and file2.php with die(); function.

include.php:

```
<? include 'file1.php';
include 'file2.php' ?>
```

file1.php

```
<? echo 'included'; die(); ?>
```

file2.php

```
<? echo 'not included'; die(); ?>
```

How can I include both files with die(); function?

Comment: What is the purpose of die() at the end of file1.php and file2.php? If you want to stop executing the included file you can use `return` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do then unfortunately it isn't possible.

`die();` will stop the script from executing at the point from where it is called.

Answer (score 10):

#### Non-English Speakers:

You can provide your question in your native language as well, and somebody here may be able to translate it for you. Just make your best effort to ask in English, and add your native tongue below.

---

If you would like to test whether the includes happened successfully, you can test the return value of the include function itself:

```
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php Example #4
if ((include 'file1.php') != 'OK') {
    die();
}
```

You may also consider [require()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) instead of include() depending on your needs:

> **require()** is identical to include() except upon failure it will also produce a fatal **E_ERROR** level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include() only emits a warning (**E_WARNING**) which allows the script to continue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to include a file, or die with a message if the include fails code sample.

```
(include('file.php')) || die('Failed to include file!');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!condition){
   include_once('./inc/header.inc.php');
   echo "Errormessage";
   include_once('./inc/footer.inc.php');
   die();
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor improvement to [LorenzoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4134022/lorenzop)'s method:

```php
(@include("file.php")) or die("Failed to include!");
// notice the @ sign!
```

This way, you save yourself 2 ugly lines of php warning when inclusion fails. Otherwise I think this is truly the best way to handle failed includes. (Also, his answer should be the accepted one.)

Answer (score 1):

If the execution of your included file is not dependent on the current file (no shared variables, functions, etc.), then use

```
file_get_contents('link_to_file.php');
```

instead of an include method. When you force the file to execute independently it will not make a effect in the script execution.

Answer (score 0):

`die()` is just an exit with an error, you can't include files with it and I don't really understand why you want to. Could you provide more details as to what you're trying to accomplish?